# Send Form Data in Firestore using Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm using Firestore in my app, i have a form in which there is an image,name and array containing name and image. Now i want it to send it to Firestore DB. I'm trying like this,

```
func saveTeamAPI()
{
    let image = teamImage.image
    let data = image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)

    // set upload path
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
    ref = db.collection("Team").addDocument(data: [
        "teamName": teamNameTxt.text!,
        "teamImage": data!,
        "players": playerArray
    ]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error adding document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm confused about one thing how can I send an image in Firestore and an array of names and images?

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use Firebase Storage, as it is an efficient way to store images. Here is how you do it: 1) Loop through an array of images and upload them one by one to storage. 2) After each successful upload, get image url and append it to array called imagesURLs.

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
let storageRef = storage.reference()

var imagesURLs = [String]()

for image in images.enumerated() {

let newImageRef = storageRef.child(/\(image.0)avatar.jpg")

let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.0)

_ = newImageRef.putData(data!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in

            guard metadata != nil else {
                print(error as Any)
                return
            }

            newImageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                guard url != nil else {
                    return
                }

                print("Avatar uploaded: \(url!.absoluteString)")

                imagesURLs.append(url!.absoluteString)
            })
        }
}
```

After you get all urls, you can use Firestore to send them as **"imageURLs": imageURLs**